# Keep the same issue resolved without taking care of the Database

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue, my client keeps asking for changes and everytime the DB guys makes changes I need to do it in the front end as well, so I need to do this more dynamically.

I have this

```
  if (data.sideBetName === 'SuitEmUp') {
    // something happens here
  }
```

so, `'SuitEmUp'` is a string coming from the DB, now, the client ask to display that in the front end as `Suit Em Up` instead of `'SuitEmUp'`, so, how do I tell JavaScript, that if the string starts with `Suit` then take it into account? otherwise, ignore it...

Comment: You should inform the client it should be "Suit 'em Up".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexOf method to check starting of the string as follows

```
if(data.sideBetName.toUpperCase().indexOf('SUIT') == 0){
  //do your logic
}
```

Comment: is there a way to ignore if comes in uppercase/lowercase ?

Comment: you can use to `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` for this scenario

Answer (score 3):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
if (/^Suit/.test(data.sideBetName) === true) {
    // something happens here
}
```

This will match any string that starts with "Suit", for example "Suit em up"

If you want to make this case-insensitive you could use: `/^Suit/i`

Comment: @Oka you are fast :) Added the missing paren

Comment: someone says something about the `indexOf`, how do I work with that ?

Comment: @StillDead indexOf is nice if you are looking for an exact match, or sub-match. Less flexible than using the regex, but (at times) more readable. In your case (@Manivannan's answer) that would be fine.

Comment: .test always returns Boolean so  no d to check dataType by ===. == is sufficient for this case

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
if ((data.sideBetName).slice(0,4) === 'Suit') { // stuff}
```

which just takes a copy of the first word of the string, so that would work for both Suit Em Up and SuitEmUp